# how to round decimals for OpenCV Mat in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

Let's say I have a `Mat A`:

```
.207001 .147804
.174070 .132521
```

Is there a way I can round the values so that `A` becomes like this?

```
.2070 .1478
.1741 .1325
```

I want those values to be part of `A` because I intend to do further math0ematical operations with it, where having less decimal places in it will affect the resulting values.

I don't want to just have `cout` display the values of `A` to 4 decimals. I need the actual values in `A` to be rounded to 4 decimals

Comment: You may get some numbers that can't be stored with 4 decimal places. How about multiplying by 10,000 and using `uint16` as the storage type.

Comment: If it helped you are free to accept my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `convertTo` function of openCV ([see convertTo](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a3f356665bb0ca452e7d7723ccac9a810)). I first convert the `Mat A` to an integer `Mat B` with a scaling factor `alpha` of 10000 and after that I convert the `Mat B` back to a double `Mat C` using a scaling factor of 0.0001. Not very elegant but it does what you want to do:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Create the given matrix A
    cv::Mat_<double> A(2, 2);
    A << 0.207001, 0.147804, 0.174070, 0.132521;

    cv::Mat B, C;
    A.convertTo(B, CV_32S, 10000); // Convert to integer with a scaling of 10000
    B.convertTo(C, CV_64F, 0.0001); // Convert back to double with a scaling of 0.0001

    std::cout << C << std::endl;

}
```